# Find a convergent subsequence in the sequence of rational primes in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In this post, my main question is how to solve the following problem:

> Consider the sequence of primes $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, \ldots$ in the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$,  find a convergent subsequence.

**My attempts:** Since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is complete, it is enough for us to construct a subsequence which is a Cauchy sequence. So after all, I have to obtain an estimate of the gaps between primes (in the $p$-adic sense). Namely, arbitrarily picking two primes $p_{m}$ and $p_{n}$, we need to estimate the gap
$$\mathrm{Gap}(m,n) :=  \vert p_m - p_n \vert_p.$$
By the non-archimedian-ness of the absolute value $\vert\cdot \vert_p$, we have
$$
\mathrm{Gap}(m,n) :=  \vert p_m - p_n \vert_p \leq \max\{ \vert p_m \vert_p, \vert p_n \vert_p \} = 1
$$
if one of the primes $p_m$ is not $p$ itself. But this wild estimate is far from enough. I'm been stucking here and making no progress besides this.

Thank you all for commenting and answering this question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $P_0$ be the set of primes. Given an infinite $P_k\subseteq P_0$ for some $k\ge 0$, there is an $r_{k+1}\in\{1,\ldots,p^{k+1}-1\}$ such that

$$P_{k+1}=\{n\in P_k:p_n\equiv r_{k+1}\pmod{p^{k+1}}\}$$

is infinite. Now use the sets $P_k$ to construct your Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems that in the definition of $N_{k+1}$, the congruence equation should be ended up with $\mod p^{k+1}$ instead of $\mod p$. Sorry for this comment if I have made it wrong.

Comment: @HetongXu: You’re absolutely right; thanks for catching it.

Comment: Following your great hint, I think that I may argue as follows: Let $P_k$ be the set of primes with the subscript index in the infinite set $N_k$. Since $P_k$ is an infinite set, and there are only finitely many residue classes modulo $p^{k+1}$, there must be at least one residue class, denoted as $\bar{r_{k+1}}$ following your notation, containing infinitely many elements in $P_k$. This is the desired $r_{k+1}$. Since there are infinitely many primes in $P_{k}$, we can choose a prime $q_{k}$ not equal to $p$. ......

Comment: ...... And by the construction, we have $k \in N_{k-1}$, and hence $q_k \equiv q_{k+1} \equiv r_k \mod p^k$. Translate this in the $p$-adic world, this means $\vert q_{k+1} - q_k \vert_p \leq p^{-k}$. So the subsequence $q_k$ is indeed a Cauchy subsequence as desired.

Comment: @HetongXu: That is indeed what I had in mind.

Comment: Sorry for commenting again and I have come up with a quite silly question: where have we used the assumption that the original sequence is the sequence of primes. I spotted that in your hint, $r_k$ cannot be zero, which is a consequence that the sequence is the sequence of primes. But where is this condition used since it seems that the pigeonhole principle can still be applied here. Sorry for such a trivial and silly question.

Comment: @HetongXu: You actually have to modify that construction a bit to ensure that you get a subsequence of the primes; I've revised it to include that modification.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it! :)

Comment: @HetongXu: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Define $a_1 :=$ the smallest prime $\neq p$, and if we have $a_m$, look at the set $\lbrace a_m + k p^{m+1} : k \in \mathbb N\rbrace$. By Dirichlet, it contains a prime (actually infinitely many); choose one of them which is $\neq p$, call it $a_{m+1}$.

The sequence $(a_i)_i$ is a subsequence of the sequence of all primes, and by definition, $\lvert a_m -a_{m+1}\rvert_p \le p^{-m-1}$.

Comment: This is overkill in at least two ways; 1) it's enough to know that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $1 \bmod p^m$ for every $m$, which can be proven using cyclotomic polynomials and is much easier than Dirichlet, 2) we don't even need this, we can repeatedly use pigeonhole instead.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Please post your own solution then.

Comment: @Cogito: it's the solution Brian is hinting at.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What do you have against actually answering a question put to you on a Q&A forum, especially since you find it so trivial?

Comment: All youre doing is "bragging" without actually producing anything worth bragging about, all the while failing to contribute. Trivializing OPs question is done more for your own ego than to actually be helpful or educational.  I mean, why are you even on this site if you dont actually answer questions?  If its so unique and insightful and easy, dont you want to compete for those precious internet points?  Or are you only here to mock, criticize others for asking or answering questions? No, no, I insist. Im genuinely interest in knowing your solution.

Comment: I fully expect it to be easy to follow, well explained, and done more concisely and simplistic than Torsten's answer.  I know you didnt speak too soon about how easy it must be, because that would be foolish to claim to have a solution before youve actually worked one out.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: I find some of your wording quite aggressive and do not like it under my answer. Qiaochu has written far more enlightening answers on this site than you and me together. I find his comment to my answer, and Brian's answer, correct, but not invalidating my answer.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for your answer. I first read your answer and the approach is quite inspiring and educational, which also helps a lot for me to understand the methods/hints introduced by Qiaochu and Brian. Thank you so much!

Comment: My comments are also objectively correct.  Answer a question or log off; we dont need people here who only want to criticize those who put in the effort to actually contribute.  I criticize, yes, but I criticize those who are wastes of space, not those who give answers.  Frankly I dont mind if people are "offended" because that is what some people need to change for the better. I will never understand the inclination of some people to build accounts on Q&A sites, just to sit on their hands mocking people who ask or answer questions. Why are you even here?!?!